# Symfony combine yaml and php configuration files

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony4

In Symfony 4, I would like to combine different configuration files for services. In the following scenario, my attempt is to import services from php configuration named services.php and then perform the other services configurations in the yaml file that imports the others services..

services.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: services.php }


services:

    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false    

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

services.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

$definition = new Definition();

$definition
    ->setAutowired(true)
    ->setAutoconfigured(true)
    ->setPublic(false)
;

$this->registerClasses($definition, 'App\\', '../src/*', '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}');

$container->getDefinition(\App\SomeClass::class)
    ->setArgument('$param', 'someValue');
```

Class file

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct(string $param)
    {
         ...
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "App\SomeClass": argument "$param"
>   of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should
>   configure its value explicitly.

Also, I'm wondering if I have to necessary to overwrite the initial _defaults definition (or others already done in by the files that imports) from the yaml or I can inherit. Not sure how these files are all merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you registering the classes in `src/*` twice, once in your `services.php` and once in your `services.yaml`.

So in the first run with `services.php` you correctly define the class and the required argument, then, in the second run with `services.yaml` the definition is being overwritten and it loses the argument again.

The minimal solution would be to exclude the `SomeClass.php` in the `services.yaml` so it won't be registered a second time:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,SomeClass.php}' # <- here I added SomeClass.php
```

It would be better though to create a separate namespace and exclude the directory in the YAML and only register this directory in the PHP-config.